# Reason for AVD not beeing compatible with project

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-studio

When Im starting my AVD emulator from within Android studio the list of devices in the emuator shows that some of my devices are not compatible with the current project.

It doesn´t show what is not compatible. Is there any way to get to know that?

My first guess was conflicting API versions. But that seems not to be the case sice several AVD:s have the same api settings and some are compatible and others not.

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
            android:name=".SetLocation"
            android:label="SetLocation"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

And a screenshot of the list:[image]

Comment: A screenshot of the list would help, alongside the manifest. I can't see your screen from here ;-)

Comment: Ok. I hope this last update will make the question clearer. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe if your applications are written for lover API version that device that you will use for testing. Can you run the application in emulator?

Comment: If you assume something and it's not the answer, you should write it as a comment to the question ;)